# All permutation of number with replacement

Tags: python, r, perl

I want to generate all possible combinations of 0,1,2's in a vector of length 4. Order of combination does not matter, ie `1100` is same as `0101,0011,1010`. so I want to select only one value ie.'`1100`'. Could you please tell me the how can I do with python/perl.

```
0000
1111
1000
2111
''''
''''
```

I tried to use itertools.product of python but getting several repeat.Thanks

Comment: You have the R tag but in the text say you are looking for a python or perl solution; can you clarify?

Comment: Since you tagged awk as well, are you ok with awk/shell solution?

Comment: strictly speaking, it is combination but not permutation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a Python approach:

```
from itertools import combinations

def perm(chars, length):
    s = ''.join([c * length for c in list(chars)])
    combs = combinations(s, length)
    combs = [''.join(comb) for comb in combs]
    combs = list(set(combs))
    combs.sort()
    return combs

for x in perm('012', 4):
    print x
```

Output:

```
0000
0001
0002
0011
0012
0022
0111
0112
0122
0222
1111
1112
1122
1222
2222
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's a Perl option using [Algorithm::Combinatorics](http://search.cpan.org/~fxn/Algorithm-Combinatorics-0.27/Combinatorics.pm):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Algorithm::Combinatorics qw/combinations_with_repetition/;

print "@$_\n" for combinations_with_repetition( [ 0 .. 2 ], 4 );
```

Output:

```
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 1
0 0 0 2
0 0 1 1
0 0 1 2
0 0 2 2
0 1 1 1
0 1 1 2
0 1 2 2
0 2 2 2
1 1 1 1
1 1 1 2
1 1 2 2
1 2 2 2
2 2 2 2
```

Answer (score 3):

One approach can be:

```
for i in range(0, 5):
  for j in range (0,5-i):
   print '0'*i+'1'*j+'2'*(4-i-j)+'\n'
```

Answer (score 3):

In R, you could do something like:

```
x <- 0:2
out <- unique(t(apply(
   do.call(expand.grid,replicate(4,x,simplify=FALSE)),
   1,
   sort)))

      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
 [1,]    0    0    0    0
 [2,]    0    0    0    1
 [3,]    0    0    0    2
 [4,]    0    0    1    1
 [5,]    0    0    1    2
 [6,]    0    0    2    2
 [7,]    0    1    1    1
 [8,]    0    1    1    2
 [9,]    0    1    2    2
[10,]    0    2    2    2
[11,]    1    1    1    1
[12,]    1    1    1    2
[13,]    1    1    2    2
[14,]    1    2    2    2
[15,]    2    2    2    2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools.product()` and append all of the values to a list, and then remove the duplicates, as long as you aren't missing some values. Here is how to remove the duplicates using `list(set(mylist))`:

```
>>> values = []
>>> values.append(8)
>>> values.append(9)
>>> values.append(9)
>>> values.append(2)
>>> values.append(8)
>>> values.append(3)
>>> values
[8, 9, 9, 2, 8, 3]
>>> values = list(set(values))
>>> values
[8, 9, 2, 3]
```

Comment: I am extremely thanks for your valuable suggestions and code. I am getting the correct result.

Comment: Remember to +1 and/or accept an answer which answered your question :)

Answer (score 1):

```
In [91]: for i in itertools.combinations_with_replacement('012', 4): print ''.join(i)
0000
0001
0002
0011
0012
0022
0111
0112
0122
0222
1111
1112
1122
1222
2222
```

Comment: Thanks for your code. This code generate all combinations which are unique but give repeat because 0111 is same as 1110.

Comment: @FIROZ: Sorry about that. I had misread the question. Check out the updated answer

Answer (score 1):

1) Fastest. R solution using `gtools` library

```
gtools::combinations(3, 4, repeats.allowed=TRUE)-1
```

2) Faster. R solution using `partitions` library

```
t(apply(partitions::compositions(4,3),2,function(d) rep(c(0,1,2),d)))
```

3) Slower. R solution using `prob` library

```
prob::urnsamples(c(0,1,2), size = 4, replace=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Perl solution using [`Math::Combinatorics`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Math%3a%3aCombinatorics)

```
use Math::Combinatorics;

use strict;
use warnings;

my $o = Math::Combinatorics->new(
    count     => 4,
    data      => [0..2],
    frequency => [4,4,4],
);

while (my @x = $o->next_multiset()) {
    print "@x\n";
}
```

Outputs:

```
2 2 2 1
2 2 2 0
2 2 2 2
2 2 1 1
2 2 1 0
2 2 0 0
2 1 1 1
2 1 1 0
2 1 0 0
2 0 0 0
1 1 1 0
1 1 1 1
1 1 0 0
1 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
```